# Reading patterns from a file vs. string literals

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with my regex. I used the following code to get all my regexes out of an ArrayList, compile it and search for matches:

```
public boolean match(String command){
    for (String regex : regexA) {
        System.out.println(regex);
        Pattern regPatter  = Pattern.compile(regex); 
        Matcher regMatcher = regPatter.matcher(command);

        if(regMatcher.find())
            return true;
    }

    return false;       
}
```

I test it like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    RegexMatcher reg = new RegexMatcher(new File("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\regex.txt"));
    System.out.println(reg.match("password cisco"));
}
```

It will return the following:

```
pas[a-z]\\s*\\w+
er\\w*\\s+(?!s).*
us[a-z]*\\s+((?!cisco).)*$
tr[a-z]*\\s+i[a-z]*\\s+\\w*\\s*
f[a-z]*\\s+f.*\\s*
en[a-z]*\\s+v.*
false
```

It will return `false`. But if I do it different like that it works:

```
public boolean match(String command){
    Pattern regPatter  = Pattern.compile("pas[a-z]\\s*\\w+"); 
    Matcher regMatcher = regPatter.matcher(command);

    if(regMatcher.find())
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

So my problem is if I enter the string directly in `Pattern.compile()` it works, but if I do like in my `match()` method it won't work.

Comment: It would be great if you could specify a more precise title for your question, e.g. "RegexMatcher differences to Pattern.compile()" instead of "Java Regex Problems". This would help others having similar problems finding your question and the answers.

Comment: I will next time.Thank you for the information. :)

Comment: You may still change it, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex.txt file should contain just single back-slashes "\", not double ones - ie. it should be :

```
pas[a-z]\s*\w+
er\w*\s+(?!s).*
us[a-z]*\s+((?!cisco).)*$
tr[a-z]*\s+i[a-z]*\s+\w*\s*
f[a-z]*\s+f.*\s*
en[a-z]*\s+v.*
```

In Java strings, backslashes are used to "escape" special characters - eg. "\n" results in a string containing just a single newline character, not a "\" followed by an "n".

Similarly, the double-backslash "\" results in a string containing a single backslash.  That is what you want for a Regex.

Files don't need to escape anything (they have newlines, etc already encoded), so they don't need to escape backslashes - which is why they only need single ones.

Comment: Thank you for your help @racraman. It was such a simple error.

Comment: Glad to help;  It's those simple ones that can drive you nuts for hours ! :)

Answer (score 0):

In a string literal, backslashes must be escaped. That means that the string `\foo`, when written as a string literal in Java Source code, must be written `"\\foo"`.

Your second example uses the literal string `"pas[a-z]\\s*\\w+"`. Which in fact corresponds to the actual string `pas[a-z]\s*\w+"`. But the string in the list isn't that string, it is `pas[a-z]\\s*\\w+`.

Answer (score 0):

To be very simple, regexps read from file are escaped differently than regexps in the Java string. for example, the correct string is `"\\w"`, but the correct line in the file is

```
\w
```